# How to add gcloud configuration so bq default is use_legacy_sql=false?

Tags: gcloud, bq

I'm lost in the Google documentation now and there must be some core trick I'm missing.

The `bq` command line tool defaults to use Legacy SQL which can be turned off for many commands by adding the parameter `--use_legacy_sql=false`. I want this to be the default so statements are interpreted as Standard SQL.

How do I configure this and other defaults for the `bq` command?

Comment: Here you go: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags

Answer (score 0):

As per the link provided by @DazWilkin (thank you), the solution is to create a `~/.bigqueryrc` file containing at least the following:

```
[query]
--use_legacy_sql=false
```

This is a command-specific configuration default (e.g. for `bq query`) but global options can be added at the top before any `[section]` has been specified. More details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags